# Add UIImage programmatically into ImageView non programmatically SWIFT

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, imageview

I have this UIImage (A Gif)

```
let macacoGif = UIImage.gifWithName("macaco")
```

And I create this ImageView on my storyboard

```
  @IBOutlet weak var fundo: UIImageView!
```

How can i add this UIImage into the ImageView ?

Comment: fundo.image = macacoGif

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UIImageView has a .image property where you can set your UIImage:

```
fundo.image = macacoGif
```